# How can I do algabraic sum?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can sum an algebraic sum.

For example, I have a function with two parameters:

```js
    function sumAlga(paramA, paramB) {
        return paramA + paramB;
    }
```

How I should do it for algebraic sum in JavaScript?

Comment: what do you mean by algebraic sum

Comment: I updated this to use a snippet, but didn't correct the mis-typed variable. Try removing the M from the end of your second param.

Comment: Apparently Algebraic Sum really just means includes negatives.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/algebraic%20sum

Comment: @Shelby115: According to that definition he just has implemented algebraic sum, if he just corrects the paramter name

Comment: If you want to be able to sum negative numbers, your code already does that.

Comment: it should be `return paramA + paramB` not `return paramA + paramBM`

Comment: Where do you get `paramBM`?

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect Code**

As "don't angry me" has said in the comments, you have `return paramA + paramBM` not `return paramA + paramB` so that should fix that (assuming that was an unintentional typo, correct me if we're wrong).

**More than two arguments**

To accomplish this with  any number of parameters you could do the following,

```
function algebraicSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;

}
```

**Usage**

```
algebraicSum(1,2,3,4) = 10;
algebraicSum(1,-2,3) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

var age_child = parseInt(10);
var age_gap = parseInt(10);

alert(age_child+age_gap);

Unlike Java or C, which are strongly typed languages, Javascript is smart and hence is also called a weakly typed language. You don't have to specify the data-type of your variable while declaring it. but in this case, you should specify the data type to match with your operations.

Comment: You should use `Number(10)` instead of `parseInt(10)` because in case of decimal values `parseInt` will eliminate decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose is to have a function which could be used as callback for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), for example.

An array with values could be summed by taking the function and a start value of zero (this is necessary, if an empty array or an array with only one item is supplied).

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

console.log([1, 2, -5].reduce(add, 0));
console.log([1].reduce(add, 0));
console.log([].reduce(add, 0));
```

The following code uses an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which has some differences to the standard function, but is sometimes shorter.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

console.log([1, 2, -5].reduce(add, 0));
console.log([1].reduce(add, 0));
console.log([].reduce(add, 0));
```